# MongoDB + Rails 3: How To Run .count() in 1.8?

Tags: mongodb

I'm not being able to run a MongoDB .count().

```
@stats = ts.count({"from" => "xpto@com"})
```

And I get the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

What am I missing here? The documentation says it should work.

Thanks

Comment: what is ts? please provide more context or code so people could understand what are you trying to do

Comment: I am trying to do a count(). If I run ts.count() it works fine. I want to pass some arguments to count(). ts is a collection.

Comment: pls update the question with your answers in the comments. Much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ts.find({"from" => "xpto@com"}).count()

Comment: that solution works but it takes a ton of time to return. to return as few as 70k documents, it takes more than 30 seconds.

Comment: If I use .count() only, without find, it takes 3 seconds to return 3 million documents.

Comment: @silkwormy: do you have index on "from"? It should greatly improve the search. Btw, even if there was a count(filter) function, how different you think it will be than find(filter).count() in performance? It still has to inspect all the documents.

Comment: There is no other way to do it. The reason the clean count() is faster is because it doesn't do much work. Neither should be that slow, by the way. Either add indexes or profile. Either way my answer is the only option available to you. Note that count() has some known performance issues. See mongodb JIRA (jira.mongodb.com) for related issues.

Comment: By the way, count is actually a seperate command sent to the server so collection.count() is not a convenience version of collection.find().count(). Adding collection.count(criteria) to the driver is probably something that'd make sense.